# Validar tipo de datos en C++

Tags: c++, validación

quisiera comprobar que la variable **numero** es un número antes de entrar a las condiciones, para que cuando el usuario escriba otra cosa diferente, mostrarle un mensaje de error. Sin embargo, me está dando un número invalido todo el rato, escriba lo que escriba.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    int numero;
    cout << "Escribe un número" << endl;
    cin >> numero;
    if (isdigit(numero)) {
        if (numero%2 == 0){
            cout << "El número " << numero << " es par" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "El número " << numero << " no es par" << endl;
        }
    } else {
            cout << "Número inválido" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int numero;
cin >> numero;
```

Si en este punto el usuario introduce una letra, `cin` se bloqueará y **dejará de leer** hasta que se resetee el flag de error.

Por otro lado, la siguiente línea:

```
if (isdigit(numero))
```

Es absurda ya que `numero` es un entero (supongamos que del 0 al 9), mientras que la función `isdigit` **valida caracteres**. La equivalencia entre ambos mundos sería la siguiente:

```
digito  caracter
  0       0x30
  1       0x31
  2       0x32
     ...
```

Así que, resumiendo: En el momento en el que un usuario introduce una letra, `cin`. Si se bloquea, los usos posteriores de `cin` no van a funcionar de forma esperable. Por otro lado, la verificación que haces es inutil ya que siempre va a resultar en un error.

Lo que tu esperas es algo más bien así:

```
int numero;
cout << "Escribe un número" << endl;
if( cin >> numero )
{ 
    if (numero%2 == 0){
        cout << "El número " << numero << " es par" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "El número " << numero << " no es par" << endl;
    }
} else {
        cout << "Número inválido" << endl;
        cin.clear(); // Reseteamos el flag de error
}
```

O también:

```
int numero;
cout << "Escribe un número" << endl;
cin >> numero;
if( !cin.fail() )
{ 
    if (numero%2 == 0){
        cout << "El número " << numero << " es par" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "El número " << numero << " no es par" << endl;
    }
} else {
        cout << "Número inválido" << endl;
        cin.clear(); // Reseteamos el flag de error
}
```